# Floating divs with width sum 100vw wrap below one another (all margins removed)

Tags: html, css

divs width sum should be 100vw.
Instead they wrap one below the other because of the 100vh scroll bar.
If I remove the 2nd div (main), the scroll bar disappears.
So is it the width or the height that creates the problem after all?

See code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/arsb3ug6

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
```

Comment: any reason for not using % instead of vw?

Comment: it's whitespace/alignment issue .. add this `vertical-align:top;` to main and remove all spaces. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arsb3ug6/1/

Comment: `display:inline-block` always adds unwanted whitespace . This is a well known and documented fact and you find tons of information about it on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use percentage values and make both items `float: left` and `display: block` to avoid the whitespace which is generated when using `inline-block`s

```css
html, body {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     min-height: 100vh;
     }
     
    
    * {
     box-sizing:border-box;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     border:0;
    }
    
    nav {
     background-color: blue;
     display:block;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     min-height:100vh;
    }
    
    main {
     background-color: yellow;
     display:block;
        float: left;
     width: 80%;
     height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main>

</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xu9b9o2n/1/

The even easier way would be to make the container (body in this case) a flex container (`dsplay: flex`), but that depends on how much you have to consider compatibility to old browsers:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use float approach or inline-block approach, not mix them, this would be the float approach..

https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/my0ee61r/

```
nav {
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

main {
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

if you use display inline-block approach consider the [gap problem](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)..

If you use vw units will not take into account the scroll bar width that is why your second element will go to a new line, to avoid this use % percentage units..

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the positions of the divs using "position: absolute, relative, sticky, fixed ..."
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```css
html, body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }


        * {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: blue;
            float:left;
            width: 20vw;
            height: 100vh;
            min-height:100vh;
        }

        main {
            background-color: yellow;
            display:inline-block;
            width: 80vw;
            height: 100vh;
            
        /*just add (position: absolute)*/
            position: absolute;     
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
      <main></main>
</body>
</html>
```